# AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I used the code provided by the keras documentation for the ImageDataGenerator
and I keep geting this error

File "C:\Users\abirf\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\deep_learning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 34, in standardize_single_array elif x.ndim == 1:

AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'ndim'

```
X_path= os.path.join('......./train_data/', 'images') # input image
Y_path = os.path.join('......../train_data/', 'masks') # ground-truth label

# we create two instances with the same arguments
data_gen_args = dict(#featurewise_center=True,
                     #featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                     rotation_range=45.,
                     #width_shift_range=0.1,
                     #height_shift_range=0.1,
                     zoom_range=[0.2])
seed = 1 
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(X_path , class_mode=None, seed=seed,batch_size = 1, 
                                                    target_size=(img_col,img_row),color_mode='grayscale')
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory( Y_path, class_mode=None, seed=seed,batch_size = 1 ,target_size=(img_col, img_row),color_mode='grayscale')

num_train = len(image_generator)
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

model = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=num_train, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1 , batch_size=16, epochs=50,callbacks=[earlystopper, checkpointer])
```

Can someone explain to me what's wrong ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Could you please post the full error trace ?

Comment: Please post it as part of the question.

Comment: You are using keras not tf.keras, only tf.keras is the one that accepts generators in fit, so you should be using fit_generator

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
model = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=num_train, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1 , batch_size=16, epochs=50,callbacks=[earlystopper, checkpointer])
```

The first argument is a `zip` object returned by the zip function. According to the Keras documentation, `model.fit()` can take several formats, the first of which being a numpy array, which is the class it's expecting since it's the one that has a `ndim` (number of dimensions) attribute, hence the error message.

https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/

No matter what you want to send as a first argument, you'll probably want to convert that `zip` object to a list. To do so, use `list(train_generator)`, and if you want a numpy array you can use `np.array(trainGeneratorList)`, `trainGeneratorList` being what you got thanks to the `list` function.

Comment: I did as you suggested and used list(train_generator ),the program run or almost one hour and then an error message related to memory appears MemoryError: Unable to allocate 64.0 KiB for an array with shape (1, 128, 128) and data type float32.Could you please give me an advice what should I change in the code ? @OctaveL

Comment: @abby It sounds like you ran out of memory. If you're feeding it enough data that allocating a list is too hard on your PC (which is quite a lot), then you'd best look into alternative solutions. Providing a generator instead of a list may be enough by itself, I don't know enough about the library to judge - you'd best open another thread with example code and all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data generator like this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class JoinedGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, input_gen, target_gen):
        self.input_gen = input_gen
        self.target_gen = target_gen

        assert len(input_gen) == len(target_gen)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.input_gen)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        x = self.input_gen[i]
        y = self.target_gen[i]

        return x, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.input_gen.on_epoch_end()
        self.target_gen.on_epoch_end()
        self.input_gen.index_array = self.target_gen.index_array

train_generator = JoinedGen(image_generator, mask_generator)

model.fit(train_generator, epochs=500, verbose=1, callbacks=[mc, neptune_cbk])
```

If you use `list`it is gonna generate all the sample before to start the training and it is gonna blow up your memory.